# runtime error while running test program in cppunit Test framework

Tags: visual-c++, cppunit

error is **Application has failed to start because MSVCP90D.dll was not found.**

Comment: So, `MSVCP90D.dll` isn't available. And what's your question?

Comment: 14 questions and 0 accepts? I know the answer, but you're not getting it from me.

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue on some of our PC, not all (don't understand why!).

But one thing is sure : **installing SP2 for VS2008** fixed most of these issues !
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

and force the following option

```
"Embed manifest": NO
```

I really hope this will work for you !

Comment: and please, consider egrunin's remark! Look at your past questions and accept some answers when it is appropriated!